# Finding duplicate values by two columns (with different values in other columns)

Tags: sql

I have a list of ID, a column `NAMESPACE` and other columns.

I would need to find IDs with same value for NAMESPACE but different values in other columns, so they are not duplicated rows.

In the example below, I would need to find rows with value `Id_1` and `NameSpaceA` that are repeated three times in the example, but that are not duplicates in the table as other fields have different value.

```
ID.      NAMESPACE    OTHER
---------------------------
Id_1     NameSpaceA     X
Id_1     NameSpaceA     Y
Id_1     NameSpaceA     Z
Id_2     NameSpaceB.    W
Id_3     NameSpaceC.    A
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add another example for the result you need to get when using the table in your example?

Comment: Exact results of the final output you expect would be helpful...  I sort of understand your problem but don't know what you want to see

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have found the solution here (output would be the 3 items with Id_1 and NameSpaceA): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758645/find-duplicate-records-based-on-two-columns

Comment: Please accept it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by with id and namespace and print the count . If count is greater than 1, it is duplicated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).