# How to delete duplicate entries from a specific field by SQL query in DSpace?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dspace

I am using DSpace version 6.3 here. I discovered that I have created duplicate entries when performing a batch import. Using the SQL query from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758742/1919069), I managed to list all the duplicates in a given field. For this example, I am using the `dc.subject` field (`metadata_field_id=57`) to list items (`dspace_object_id`) that have duplicate values in `dc.subject` field.

Below is the query that I used:

```
SELECT metadata_value_id,
       dspace_object_id,       
       text_value
FROM   (SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dspace_object_id, text_value) AS cnt
FROM   metadatavalue where metadata_field_id=57) e
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Below is the sample list generated from that query:

| metadata_value_id | dspace_object_id | text_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 503018 | 13f07109-7797-4d5b-a8bd-1f9e91a2433d | pompanos |
| 503021 | 13f07109-7797-4d5b-a8bd-1f9e91a2433d | pompanos |
| 503217 | 233d1e67-b698-4e90-8e70-a175776b2d80 | pests |
| 503219 | 233d1e67-b698-4e90-8e70-a175776b2d80 | pests |
| 83574 | 47753988-fc2a-4416-b20d-acbff6e256de | Penaeus monodon |
| 10800 | 47753988-fc2a-4416-b20d-acbff6e256de | Penaeus monodon |
| 531520 | 50965923-bc65-4fdf-af61-2c8debdfe057 | Penaeus monodon |
| 531521 | 50965923-bc65-4fdf-af61-2c8debdfe057 | Penaeus monodon |
| 483882 | 57d0544c-1825-431a-acf9-eb835c24920b | development |
| 483879 | 57d0544c-1825-431a-acf9-eb835c24920b | development |

Based on the table above, you can see that there are 2 occurrences (others have more than 2) of a `text_value` in the same item (`dspace_object_id`).

My question is how can I delete the duplicate but retain the first occurrence?
In the table above, rows with the following `metadata_value_id` should be deleted:

```
503021  
503219  
83574 <-- This should be deleted instead of 10800 because 10800 was put in (inserted) first.  
531521
483882 <-- Should be deleted instead of 483879 because of the same reason above.
```

I'm hoping to do this via SQL query alone because what I have done before is import this list to a Google spreadsheet, remove the duplicates there using a [Remove Duplicates add-on](https://www.ablebits.com/docs/google-sheets-find-duplicate-rows/), download it as a CSV, and then [use that CSV to update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663283/1919069) the `metadatavalue` table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'first occurrence' means the one with smaller metadata_value_id:

```
delete from metadatavalue as Not1stOcc
where exists (select * 
              from metadatavalue as FirstOcc 
              where FirstOcc.text_value = Not1stOcc.text_value
                and FirstOcc.metadata_value_id < Not1stOcc.metadata_value_id
            )
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

**For my future reference**, I modified tinazmu's answer that worked for my use case.

```
DELETE FROM metadatavalue as Not1stOcc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT metadata_value_id, dspace_object_id, text_value, metadata_field_id
    FROM metadatavalue AS FirstOcc 
    WHERE FirstOcc.text_value = Not1stOcc.text_value
      AND FirstOcc.metadata_field_id = Not1stOcc.metadata_field_id
      AND FirstOcc.dspace_object_id = Not1stOcc.dspace_object_id
      AND FirstOcc.metadata_field_id = Not1stOcc.metadata_field_id
      AND metadata_field_id = 57
      AND FirstOcc.metadata_value_id < Not1stOcc.metadata_value_id
            )
```